# Конвертация utc к нужному времени Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, такая проблема - копировал данные с одной базы (1) в другую базу (2), и в базе 1 время отличается на +3ч., число строк в таблице 120 и у всех время отличается на +3 часа, как заменить в базе 2 время с нужным часовым поясом ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table
   set date_column=date_column-1/8
```

1/8 - это разница в сутках, т.е. 1/24*3

Comment: а можно пожалуйста пример для +2 спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets `-1/12` разумеется :) собственно никто не мешает писать прямо формулой, что бы не считать 1/24*2

Comment: Заработался, спасибо большое ;)

Comment: а если в зимнее время +2 а летнее +3 как сделать ?

Comment: @Ethernets Часовой пояс в самих данных не хранится. Данные интерпретируются в том поясе который был в настройках БД/сессии в момент занесения значения в базу и в момент их получения из БД. Так что мы просто модифицируем само значение в расчете на то, что настройки сессии не меняются. Если у вас данные туда сюда сами плавают, может стоит смотреть настройки ... Или думать о своих механизмах интерпретации времени. А так то добавить вместо вычитания - просто заменить знак ...